# Sql Server How to skip excel sheets that don't exists

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, openrowset

I used OPENROWSET to insert excel file into table

```
INSERT INTO [Program_2].[dbo].[Current]
        ([Div],[Date],[HomeTeam],[AwayTeam])
SELECT [Div],[Date],[HomeTeam],[AwayTeam]
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
  'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\Users\2016-2017.xls', [B1$])
```

But if a [B1$] sheet does not exist I don't know how to skip that table and insert another table for exaple [D1$]. I try using EXISTS but I have no luck

Comment: You are going to need to provide a little bit of context here. I can't understand what you mean about a sheet not existing and inserting into another table...

Comment: I have 10 tables in a single workbook sometimes one sheet is deleted so i like to skip that one and insert other ones because SQL give me a error

Answer (score 0):

Newer Sql servers I believe support a "try" command.  That may be an easy way to get through what you are trying to do.  This would cause the Sql sever to try to write to the page that does not exist, fail, but allow your code to continue.

Comment: The documentation for the `try/catch` block can be found here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx